# Error: "expected ‘)’ before string constant"

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to run a C program in Ubuntu (using the gcc compiler), and for some reason it's not allowing me to use the strcpy function. On the second line of code below:

```
char test[10];
strcpy(test, "Hello!");

char c[2] = "A";
strcpy(test, c);
```

I get the following errors:

```
testChTh.c:56:14: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 strcpy(test, "Hello!");
              ^
testChTh.c:59:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 strcpy(test, c);
 ^
testChTh.c:59:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-int]
testChTh.c:59:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
testChTh.c:59:1: error: conflicting types for ‘strcpy’
In file included from testChTh.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: previous declaration of ‘strcpy’ was here
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
```

I've included the following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

I've tried using strcpy in a new file with nothing extra, with the same error. I've also tried using:

```
memset(test, '\0', sizeof(test));
```

immediately before using strcpy, to no avail.

I've checked all of my opening parenthesis, and they all have a corresponding closing ). Also, when I comment out the strcpy line, the error goes away.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the double quotes match?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307762/error-expected-before-string-constant#10307781) If not, show us the minimal code that produces the error and how you're compiling.

Comment: Does it really say `expected ‘)’` rather than `expected ‘(’` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Following the comment from @EdHeal, meaning that both `'"'` double quotes are ASCII char `34` or `0x22` and not a unicode *open-double quote* or *close-double quote* you might see in a word-processor.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I retyped to make sure. I put the words inside of the auto-completed quotations.

Comment: @Schwern No, I saw that earlier and from what I see it only has to do with extern, which I'm not using. I'll provide more code momentarily.

Comment: Without the code we can only speculate

Comment: @Barmar Yes ')' is what it says.

Comment: It looks like you tried and failed to include the error message as an image. Don't do that; copy-and-paste the error message as text.

Comment: The source file containing `strcpy(test, "Hello!");` cannot see the `#include <string.h>` header file. Are you using separate header/source files, and did you remember to `#include "yourheader.h"` in the source file?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm only coding in a single file, so no I don't think so.

Comment: Why is this marked as off-topic? If this is off-topic then surely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307762/error-expected-before-string-constant?noredirect=1&lq=1) must be off-topic too, but it's not. I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char test[10];
strcpy(test, "Hello!");

char c[2] = "A";
strcpy(test, c);
```

If I understand correctly, you have those lines lines *at file scope*. The line

```
strcpy(test, "Hello!");
```

is a *statement*, and statements are legal only inside a function body. Because the compiler wasn't expecting a statement at that point, it tried to interpret that line as a declaration.

The following, based on your code, is legal (though it doesn't do anything useful):

```
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char test[10];
    strcpy(test, "Hello!");

    char c[2] = "A";
    strcpy(test, c);
}
```

Comment: Oh, good catch... So it was a MCVE after all...,  but then where did he include the header files?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Look at the line numbers in the error messages. The code is a small fragment of is actual source file, but it's enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're 100% right, problem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah got it, your catch made sense, I just didn't pick up on the line numbers...